# Angular Material ("@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc0") mat-accordion with multiple components' selectors

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am working on an Angular 5 application where I have to load multiple components dynamically based on what components the user pick to display using `ComponentFactoryResolver`. In each component template, I have `mat-expansion-panel`. After the components are loaded dynamically, it looks like a "normal" `Accordion`. However, `mat-accordion` won't work as it allows the user to open multiple `expansion-panel` at the same time.

My Plunker to demonstrate my question: [Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/03ublQRPDPgFNDk0Y1qB?p=preview)

Angular Material's Documentation Plunker: [Angular Material Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/qy6cY66KxXkKXDbwnmvy?p=preview)

Is there a way to have my example's accordion behaves like the Angular Material's example's accordion?

Thanks

EDIT: I have tried `multi` input which is default to `false`.

Comment: Material accordion has a @Input parameter called `multi` that you can set to true or false which determines whether or not more than one panel can be opened at a time

Comment: It is default to `false`. I tried the `multi` input. Thanks though.

Comment: Was hoping that it was defaulting true for some reason. Since mat-expansion-panel needs to be in the same component to manage the open/close state itself you'd have to shift those panels up to the parent or you have to create an @Output and have the parent manage the state directly (force all other closed when one is open)

Comment: Is there away to reference to a template variable in the Parent component? All those expansion-panel are in children components. I am hoping `accordion` input that `expansion-panel` provides would work..

Comment: This one isn't straight forward, and you'll need experience with EventEmitters. The expansion-panel already has built in event emitters that you can tie into, and then from your custom component's directives (the html in the parent) you can then tie them together. Not straight forward, and I'd recommend trying to get the expansion-panels inside the parent component rather that work this way.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'd live with it as I can't put the expansion-panels in the parent component. PrimeNG Accordion works like what I want to achieve but then changing all the components (expansion-panel, 22 of them) just hurts my brain...

Answer (score 2):

multi="true" needs to be set at mat-accordion level for this to work.
     e.g-> `mat-accordion multi="true"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it wasn't the solution. As I added components dynamically as `mat-accordion-panel` to the `mat-accordion`. The `panels` don't recognize the `mat-accordion` as their parent. I needed to use `TemplateRef` and the like